# Foreign language meta questions shouldn't be migrated

Tags: discussion, meta, languages

This question is about [my post that was migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214253/why-is-the-welcome-message-in-english?noredirect=1).

With the arrival of new websites in different languages, I cannot help but to think that it will create some confusion for were the issues that are coming with these sites will be addressed.

Every sites are going to have their own meta but issues might be discovered outside the boundaries of that website so it might make it difficult for users to address the found issue in a foreign language.

In any different sites, it works since it is all the same language so it might be addressed anywhere and since English is Stack Exchange's primary language, it will be understood no matter where you migrate it. But migrating my question to another website might be causing a few issues :

- The language of the question will not be understood by all users
- It will make a various language website
- Comments and answer in a different language won't make sense to the users
- It will create mutli-language questions where you only understand part of the post

I can already see the comments telling me that the question wasn't asked on the right site and that it is my job to make sure I post it on the right site... I agree... But not for these site no.

- I cannot address an issue in a language I do not understand
- I will not simply try to use a translator that might make my question barely understandable

This is going to create a few problems with the bug / feature requests and stuff. I do not speak Portuguese but I can find plenty bugs on the site and report them so the fact that shouldn't go on that website in the first place isn't a valid argument in my opinion.

Comment: [Your question without redirect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214253/why-is-the-welcome-message-in-english?noredirect=1)

Comment: The links on this are not visible to me.

Answer (score 9):

I cannot say for other SE sites, but in Stack Overflow em Português, I believe that you can feel free to ask and answer in english (on meta, of course), and we will do the best effort to translate it properly and keep both versions. Dealing with the problems outside of "our" meta (pt) will cause redundant reports, split proposals, and we will loose the coordination to solve properly the problem.